# How can I limit the responses to only the questions that I have asked?

Tags: discussion

How can I limit the responses to only the questions that I have asked.  I find everyones answers on different questions interesting but I cant go 20 or more emails per day to find what I'm interested in

Comment: @bmike I think, it's a question about [filters for Q&A Emails](http://stackexchange.com/filters) and may be moved to meta or deleted alltogether.

Comment: Thanks @klanomath. Let's see if this fits better